# Can nervous disorders be cured? Will enough research be the answer?

Tags: neurology

I have searched every nook of the internet and I couldn't find a clear and to-the-point answer. Well my story is that I am a young BSc student who wants to do research on neurological conditions because as far as my knowledge goes neurologists cannot do anything about ANYTHING, things like dementia and brain damage lead the person to become completely destroyed and then eventual death is what every doctor has to see. As of current.

So I am asking if we can develop eventually effective treatments for let's say OCD or Alzheimer's? Or that will never happen because of other factors in the ecosystem and it's the rule of the nature that some people are just unfit to survive? If that's possible, and about to happen in my life time -- i.e., I can contribute -- I am in. I am gonna get a doctorate in one of the life sciences and start doing something. Like discovering genes, or understanding the pathophysiology, or discovering drugs, whatever I am competent in and able to. I just cannot see people suffer like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, levodopa type treatments for parkinsons.

epilepsy: 
In 2017, 116 children were randomly assigned to undergo epilepsy surgery or receive medical treatment. After 12 months, 77% of the children who had undergone surgery were seizure free compared with 7% who received medical treatment.

Check news and histories of advances in neuroscience and neurology.

Every year drugs improve, it's best to stay objective in the face of mind dysfunction, meditate.

Comment: But will enough research lead to such advances that neurological conditions will be cured? If not, can the patients be significantly benefited in the near future? Thanks in advance.
Edit : I'll try to stay objective my best.